# What is the difference between these two strcmp() functions in PHP?

Tags: php, strcmp

I'm having trouble understanding the difference between

A) `return strcmp($digest, $signature) == 0;`

and

B) `return strcmp($digest, $signature);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally `strcmp()` returns -1, 0, or 1 if the first string is less than, equal to, or greater than the second respectively.  By comparing the result of that to 0 in

```
return strcmp($digest, $signature) == 0;
```

the result of `strcmp()` is turned to a boolean that only tests for equality rather than greater than/less than by comparison.  The function will return `TRUE` if the two strings are equal (`strcmp() == 0`), and `FALSE` otherwise, discarding the other greater/less than information.

Answer (score 2):

The first one returns whether two strings are equal, while the second one returns whether two strings are not equal.

> int strcmp ( string $str1 , string $str2 )
>
> Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

A) will return true if two strings are equal, false otherwise
B) will return the result of strcmp

Note: Strcmp returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal.